# How to run multiple locusts each with different parameters?

Tags: locust

I am trying to load our online gaming platform which has many games in it that can be accessed/played via RESTful endpoints.
I want to use `locust` to simulate players where each player plays a certain kind of a game. I want to have a player locust class something like:

```
class Player(HttpLocust):
    def __init__(self, host, config, delay_between_plays):
        super().__init__()
        self.task_set = Game(config)
        self.wait_time = delay_between_plays
        self.host = host
```

My game taskset is like this:

```
class Game(TaskSet):
    def __init__(self, config, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.config = config

    @task
    def play(self):
        ...
        ...
```

I don't see anywhere in docs where it mentions how to do this. Would appreciate some inputs.

Comment: Hi! I dont quite follow what you want to do. You want to have different locusts play different games. Is there a reason you can't use multiple locust classes? Because otherwise that would be the recommended solution.

Comment: @Cyberwiz yea that’s what I ended up doing